# Loading a Search and Retrieve via URL (SRU) in php with simplexml_load_string returns an empty object

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Im trying to load search result from an library api using Search and Retrieve via URL (SRU) at : https://data.norge.no/data/bibsys/bibsys-bibliotekbase-bibliografiske-data-sru

If you see the search result links there, its looks pretty much like XML but when i try like i have before with xml using the code below, it just returns a empty object,

```
SimpleXMLElement {#546}
```

whats going on here?

My php function in my laravel project:

```
public function bokId($bokid) {
    $apiUrl = "http://sru.bibsys.no/search/biblio?version=1.2&operation=searchRetrieve&startRecord=1&maximumRecords=10&query=ibsen&recordSchema=marcxchange";
    $filename = "bok.xml";
    $xmlfile = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
    file_put_contents($filename, $xmlfile); // xml file is saved.
    $fileXml = simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
    dd($fileXml);
}
```

If i do:

```
 dd($xmlfile);
```

instead, it echoes out like this: [image]

Making me very confused that i cannot get an object to work with. Code i present have worked fine before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the data your being provided ha changed format, but the data is still there and you can still use it. The main problem with using something like `dd()` is that it doesn't work well with SimpleXMLElements, it tends to have it's own idea of what you want to see of what data there is.

In this case the namespaces are the usual problem.  But if you look at the following code you can see a quick way of getting the data from a specific namespace, which you can then easily access as normal.  In this code I use `->children("srw", true)` to say fetch all child elements that are in the namespace srw (the second argument indicates that this is the prefix and not the URL)...

```
$apiUrl = "http://sru.bibsys.no/search/biblio?version=1.2&operation=searchRetrieve&startRecord=1&maximumRecords=10&query=ibsen&recordSchema=marcxchange";
$filename = "bok.xml";
$xmlfile = file_get_contents($apiUrl);
file_put_contents($filename, $xmlfile); // xml file is saved.
$fileXml = simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);

foreach ( $fileXml->children("srw", true)->records->record as $record)  {
    echo "recordIdentifier=".$record->recordIdentifier.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This outputs...

```
recordIdentifier=792012771
recordIdentifier=941956423
recordIdentifier=941956466
recordIdentifier=950546232
recordIdentifier=802109055
recordIdentifier=910941041
recordIdentifier=940589451
recordIdentifier=951721941
recordIdentifier=080703852
recordIdentifier=011800283
```

As I'm not sure which data you want to retrieve as the title, I just wanted to show the idea of how to fetch data when you have a list of possibilities.  In this example I'm using XPath to look in each `<srw:record>` element and find the `<marc:datafield tag="100"...>` element and in that the `<marc:subfield code="a">` element.  This is done using `//marc:datafield[@tag='100']/marc:subfield[@code='a']`.  You may need to adjust the `@tag=` bit to the datafield your after and the `@code=` to point to the subfield your after.

```
$fileXml = simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
$fileXml->registerXPathNamespace("marc","info:lc/xmlns/marcxchange-v1");

foreach ( $fileXml->children("srw", true)->records->record as $record)  {
    echo "recordIdentifier=".$record->recordIdentifier.PHP_EOL;

    $data = $record->xpath("//marc:datafield[@tag='100']/marc:subfield[@code='a']");
    $subData=$data[0]->children("marc", true);
    echo "Data=".(string)$data[0].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the working solution and explanation!

Comment: Nigel, I'm wondering if you could also help me get data from the actual records. Like an example of how to get a string book name of say the first record. I've tried so much after your post, and searched for similar code,but I did not get any further. (things i've tried https://hastebin.com/bumuqimaba.pl). I feel im so close to actually get to using this api but I need help. Would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I've added an example, not entirely sure which fields you were after, but hope this helps.

Comment: It is truly helpful, thank you so much, appreciate it alot.